# Unity 3d when camera is closer the shadows getting clipped weirdly

Tags: unity, shadows, unity-ui

When in distance the shadows are appearing correctly but when getting near to the shadows it is getting clipped in a weird way. I was not able to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you include more information about your light setup, and shadow settings for the current project?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the setting you are looking for is in Project Settings > Quality > Shadow Distance. This can be configured per quality setting.

More info here: [Unity Manual Quality Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-QualitySettings.html)